# CentOS - using PXE to install it on my host ( kickstart configuration )

Tags: linux, centos, kickstart, pxe

I am trying to install an OS from our server through PXE ( Preboot Execution Environment ).

However, on my host, I have two disks say A ( /dev/sda ) and B ( /dev/sdb )

The default installation path goes to disk A while I expect to install it on disk B. ( No selection appears )

Should I edit the kickstart file or there are some other configuration files I should modify ?

1.Can I write a bash to let my kickstart file to choose which disk to
   install ?

2.The other way is to give a fixed path and then just install the OS on that disk.

Please give your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify the kickstart file by adding an `ignoredisk` line in the first part, see the [kickstart doc](https://github.com/rhinstaller/pykickstart/blob/master/docs/kickstart-docs.rst):

> By default, all disks will be available for partitioning. Only one of the following three options may be used.

```
ignoredisk --drives=sdb
ignoredisk --only-use=sda
ignoredisk --interactive
```